# Sketch Plugin: How to programmatically make a layer exportable?

Tags: javascript, plugins, sketch-3, cocoascript

So, in [Sketch](https://www.sketchapp.com/), you can mark a layer/group as exportable.

[image]

And then the layer/group can be exported as .png/.svg/.pdf etc. I was trying to make a Sketch Plugin recently, where I need to mark a layer/group as exportable from code. A layer in code is represented using `MSLayer` and group is `MSLayerGroup`. The sketch documentation is not mature enough yet, so I used [ClassDump](http://stevenygard.com/projects/class-dump/) to extract all the headers that has been used in the app. I have been looking for a method that might seem to do my job, but it has been days and am still out of luck. Can anybody please help me out in this regard?

Answer (score 1):

Sketch supports slice and export to image. You can use `- (void)saveArtboardOrSlice:(id)arg1 toFile:(id)arg2;`
 method of `MSDocument`.

This is almost how to do it.

```
var loopLayerChildren = [[layerToExport children] objectEnumerator],
    rect = [MSSliceTrimming trimmedRectForSlice:layer],
    useSliceLayer = false,
    exportFilePath,
    slice;

// Check for MSSliceLayer and overwrite the rect if present
while (layerChild = [loopLayerChildren nextObject]) {
    if ([layerChild class] == 'MSSliceLayer') {
        rect  = [MSSliceTrimming trimmedRectForSlice:layerChild];
        useSliceLayer = true;
    }
}

slice = [MSExportRequest requestWithRect:rect scale:1];

if (!useSliceLayer) {
    slice.shouldTrim = true;
}

// export to image file
[(this.document) saveArtboardOrSlice: slice toFile:exportFilePath];
```

Reference from @GeertWill's [sketch-to-xcode-assets-catalog plugin](https://github.com/GeertWille/sketch-to-xcode-assets-catalog/blob/398d2ea2cfbe340fa334b8002ac534c889893cfd/library/main.js#L143-L194).

Comment: Thanks, I will check it asap and get back to you.